# An honest die is thrown 8 times; let X be the number of twos and let Y be the number of fours. Find the joint pmf of X and Y and calculate P(X=Y).

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

> An honest die is thrown 8 times; let $X$ be the number of twos and let $Y$ be the number of fours. Find the joint pmf of $X$ and $Y$ and calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$.

This question is too big to manually draw a table for so I'm having trouble solving it. Can anyone help with the joint pmf? Calculating $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$ should be straightforward once I have the joint pmf.

I know that for either $X$ and $Y$ alone, the pmf will be ${{8}\choose{k}}(1/6)^k(5/6)^{8-k}$

Comment: Do you mean to have $\binom{10}{k}$ instead of $\binom8k$ there, and shouldn't $n$ be replaced with $8$ as well?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Comment: No worries. I wish I could answer your actual question, but I'm following with interest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint distribution is not just $\Pr[X=x,Y=y]=\Pr[X=x| Y=y]\Pr[Y=y]$?

The last form is easy to handle, right? You just need to be aware that $\Pr[X=x|Y=y]=\Pr[Z=z]$ for the random variable $Z$ that counts the number of two in $8-y$ die. However you need to take in account that these $8-y$ die must be all different of four.

That is: $\Pr[X=x|Y=y]$ means "probability that will be exactly $x$ two's in $8-y$ die, and the other $8-y-x$ die will be distinct of two or four".

Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Discrete_case) also. For a "shortcut" to an easier way to handle this joint distribution take a look at the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure. Is the joint pmf of X and Y in this case
$P(X=x, Y=y) = {{10-y} \choose {x}} (1/6)^x(5/6)^{10-y-x} {{10} \choose {y}} (1/6)^y(5/6)^{10-y}$ ?

Comment: we have that $$\Pr[X=x|Y=y]=(1/6)^x(4/6)^{8-y-x}\binom{8-y}{x}$$ and $$\Pr[Y=y]=(1/6)^y(5/6)^{8-y}\binom8y$$ Writing as a multinomial coefficent we have that $\binom{8-y}x\binom8y=\binom8{x,y,8-x-y}$, thus $$\Pr[X=x,Y=y]=\binom8{x,y,8-x-y}(1/6)^{x+y}(4/6)^{8-x-y}$$

Comment: In the final equation, why don't you have the $(5/6)^{8-y}$ ?

Comment: because the probabilities for $x,y$ and $8-x-y$ must add up to $1$. That is: there are $4/6$ of probabilities that a die is not a two or a four. However I see now that I have a mistake in the formula for $\Pr[X=x|Y=y]$ somewhere...

Comment: ok, I saw my fault... the above need to be correct to $$\Pr[X=x|Y=y]=(1/5)^x(4/5)^{8-y-x}\binom{8-y}x$$ Then we get the desired expression.